# What is the analogy of cross section for particle decays?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, scattering-cross-section, half-life

So if two particles are fired at each other the chance they interact is the cross section of the interaction. What is the equivalent term for the chance that a particle decays into certain particles? If it is the branching ratio, then what does the decay width mean?

Comment: You seem to know it is the decay width. Branching ratios, by contrast, compare widths of decay to different product particles.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://cms.cern/news/what-do-we-mean-cross-section-particle-physics) how the cross section has been used in particle physics.

> Early collision experiments were intended to measure the size of particles from their collision rate. Rutherford’s experiment, which collided alpha particles and gold nuclei in 1911, revealed that nuclei are much smaller than previously supposed. But soon, disparities arose

.....

> Even though [hard spheres](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/419890/how-is-the-cross-section-related-to-the-probability-of-a-process) is the wrong mental image, the term “cross section” stuck,

and the quantum *probability* of interaction is necessary to calculate quantum particle interaction crossections.

[There exists a calculable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate_2)  quantum *probability* distribution for the lifetime of a  particular decay, as can be seen here.